# How to redirect same path in other blog with javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

i am using blogspot.com
i need redirect my blogs going other blog with same path/page

example:

```
From: [www.myblog.blogspot.com/2013/11/blogging-tips.html]
to: [www.newblog.blogspot.com/2013/11/blogging-tips.html]
```

i just want replace ("`www.myblog.blogspot.com`") with ("`www.newblog.blogspot.com`")

Any body have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.host = 'www.newblog.blogspot.com';
```

See this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp